# Is this way to check Api Security right?

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf, security, oauth

I have rest Api which I used internally and also used by third party.My question is:I use oauth authentication in this when api called from third party I use to check signature but now i have to allow my internal application call without checking the oauth authentication because to reduce overhead.So I planned get a IP address from where my API called and on that basis I decide oauth authentication required or not.But I have to know my own android application call this Api so in that case IP track possible and ya this whole technique is good or it have drawbacks...My Api is in c#.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OAuth you can store the access keys locally on the android device and reuse them when you want to use your own service again. Don't do any authentication based on IP addresses as the IP address on your phone is dynamic, meaning it changes often rendering any IP authentication system useless.

Comment: Thanks for reply.Can i use authentication based on IP addresses in other internal applications because those have static IP addresses and in android case i use fixed token but i will be hacked is'nt it????

Comment: I don't see any reason for you to get hacked as long as you use OAuth 1.0A or later releases. As for IP based authentication, the only time it's practical to use it would be for example when you want to restrict access to your websites control panel